# Ясновидение или ясновиденье?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно пишется: *ясновидение* или *ясновиденье?*

Answer (score 2):

**Ясновидение** ― основная форма (она указана в словаре),  но в разговорной и поэтической речи встречается форма **"ясновиденье".**

(1)  Его охотничье **ясновиденье**, вероятно, тоже как-то было связано с этой хрупкой душевной организацией. [Фазиль Искандер. Сандро из Чегема (Книга 3) (1989)

(2)
Будущее вижу так подробно,
Словно Ты его остановил.
Я сейчас предсказывать способна
Вещим **ясновиденьем** сивилл (Борис Пастернак).